# Show that $f$ is convex in $I$ such that $f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(y))$

Tags: functions, continuity, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

$f$ is continuous in $I$

Show that if $f$ satisfies the condition 
 $f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(y))$ so it's convex

What I have to show here is $f(k_1y_1+k_2y_2+..k_ny_n)<k_1f(y_1)+k_2f(y_2)+...k_nf(y_n)$ such that $k_1+k_2+...+k_n=1$

The problem  is I don't know how to find  those coefficients $k$.

Comment: Should i delet my question or just keep it

Comment: @user515918 If you have found out that this question is already answered in another post then why should you keep it?